# Which one is correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

1. 这家餐馆菜都很好吃的
2. 这家餐馆的菜都很好吃

What's the correct form to say "all the food of that restaurant it's delicious" ?

Comment: The standard mandarin is (2). Colloquially some people would say (1) too, especially in the Wu dialect area.

Comment: Dropping the last 的 in (1), then it is correct; otherwise it sounds childish.

Comment: People say (1) pretty frequently. IMO the syntax is similar to 这家餐馆挺大的. Here "菜都很好吃的" is acting as an adjective component. So in the case of (1), the subject is 餐馆, while in (2), the subject is 菜.

Answer (score 3):

Number 2 is correct. 
Number 1 translates as This restaurant food is delicious. (Does not make sense)
Number 2 translates as The food in this restaurant is delicious. (Should be what you are looking for)

Comment: Fine, and how to say just "all this dishes/food"? Do I have to put 个?

Comment: You can say 所有菜 or 所有这些菜.

Answer (score 3):

I am a native speaker of Chinese. Both can be understood by me, but the second one makes me feel more comfortable.

The reason is probably because that sometimes 的 can be omitted. For sentence (1), changing to  这家餐馆的菜都很好吃 is correct I think.

I used to live in northern China, and I am living in southern China. Perhaps sentence (1) is correct in some dialects, maybe Wu dialect?

But sentence (1) is not 普通话，so if you are preparing for an exam, forget what i said.

Comment: So I should take the "de" away at the end... But the "de" before "cai" is necessary? Or is correct even without it?

Comment: @Chiara "de" before "cai" is necessary. Without it seems weird.